# Containing file and class name must match ( Scriptable Object )

Tags: unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

[image]

I have this problem while trying to assign my scriptable object and the window which shows me the error pop-up, any idea :>>?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. If anyone is having the same problem as me, make sure the script's name ( which creates scriptable object ) matches to the class name

Answer (score 1):

The error happens either when you make a scriptable object class in a file under a different name. For example, your file name is "Inventory.cs" and your scriptable object name is "Item". Unity can't find the scriptable object since its under a different file name.

To fix that, you just have to make a new script file called "Item.cs" and copy the class "Item" into the new file.

Just remember that whenever you make a new scriptable object, make sure to place it in its own file with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is struggling to assign a reference that the scriptable object has in the inspector make sure that the object you are trying to assign is a prefab.